# TweetDeck and real via retweets

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

Is it possible to configure TweetDeck to do native retweets showing "via personname" instead of "via TweetDeck"? I played around in the settings, but couldn't find such a setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The "via.." comes via the program name to which the oAuth keys are tied to, and these are defined in the twitter API registration page for the application.

Comment: Ok. Seems like Twitter native client for OSX can handle it.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

All third party applications will always say via the application that made the tweet.

When you do a retweet, you get the following:

[image]

Clicking `Retweet now` does the same as a retweet from the web interface, but, it says via Tweetdeck - this is in addition and you do not loose anything.

If you do `Edit then Retweet`, it will place that person's tweet in a new tweet by yourself, again with the via.

So sorry, you can't do it without, but, as I said, you don't loose anything, it simply says `Via Tweetdeck` instead of `Via Web`.